# How can I add custom properties to a field class for output in template?

Tags: python, django, field

I would like to add a custom field which can provide additional properties for handling the individual output of in a template. For instance here's my class:

```
class CustomField(CharField):
    suffix = "things"
```

And my accompanying `field.html` where I've added the `field.suffix` block:

```
<div class="controlGroup clearfix {% if field.errors %}error{% endif %}">
   <label class="controlLabel" for="{{ field.auto_id }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
   <div class="controls">
       {{ field }}
       {% if field.suffix %}
           <span class="suffix">{{ field.suffix }}</span>
       {% endif %}
       {% if field.errors %}
           <span class="helpInline">{{ field.errors }}</span>
       {% endif %}
   </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately the suffix block simply doesn't output.

EDIT: To clarify, both current answers below are targeted at adding widget attributes. I'm actually trying to add a custom string for use in the template, not a custom CSS class.

Comment: Do you want to pass a value(string) to the template from your views? Or do you want to declare a variable inside your template? Explain clearly.

Comment: I want to declare the variable `suffix` within the CustomField class and then be able to output that variable within a template by calling `field.suffix`.

Comment: You cannot render a variable to template in forms. You can pass only attributes and their corresponding values from forms and you can access them using jQuery in your template.

Comment: There must be a way to do get to the end goal of what I'm proposing, I'm just not sure how deep I need to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually did this by creating my own widget:

```
class UsernameInput(TextInput):
    """
    Creates a widget specifically for appending the username suffix as a label
    """  9 
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        widget = super(UsernameInput, self).render(name, value, attrs)
        widget += u'<span class="field-suffix">@%s</span>' % USERNAME_DOMAIN_PART
        return mark_safe(widget)
```

And then in my signup form by specifying the widget like so:

```
username = forms.EmailField(label="Preferred Username",
                            widget=UsernameInput(),
                            error_messages={'invalid': "Please enter a valid email address"})
```

Answer (score 0):

For your simple example, you can override the [`attrs` dictionary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#customizing-widget-instances) of the *widget* that you use in for your form field, you don't need to create a custom field.

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):
  some_field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'suffix'})
```

If you really want to create a custom field, you need to create a custom widget and control the `render` method. Depending in what type of form control you want to render, you inherit your custom widget from the equivalent provided by django.

Comment: Well I should mention my custom field has a number of other differences that I think warrant a new Class, I was just trimming my code for the question :)

Comment: If you provide a trimmed question, expect a trimmed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes can be passed to form fields by two ways. I have given the example code below.

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
            'field1' : forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class': 'suffix'}),
            'field2' : forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class': 'suffix'}),
        }
```

OR

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(forms.ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.fields['field1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'suffix'
        self.fields['field2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'suffix'
```

You can use **widgets** as given in first example or in **init** as given in second example. Both will work.

**EDIT:** Any attribute can be passed to the django form field using the above example.

Comment: If you look at the template I'm using you should see I'm not trying to add an HTML attribute to the widget but another tag for use with the field template to be handled independent of the field widget. Sorry if my question was confusing.